# Using findfile in my program

Tags: c, recursion, header, find

I am trying to incorporated the findfile function into my code and I am getting the error "Segmentation error (core dumped).  I understand what this means, I just can not find the error in the code.  If someone could point it out or guide me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include "find.h"       // utilize findfile function

#define NAMESIZE 256
#define TOKENSIZE 100


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int choice = -1;
char *input_dir_name, *dirpath, *chptr;
struct stat statbuf;

input_dir_name = (char *) malloc(NAMESIZE * sizeof(char));
dirpath = (char *) malloc(NAMESIZE * sizeof(char));
printf("\n");
printf("SELECT THE FUNCTION YOU WANT TO EXECUTE:\n");
printf("1. Find the 3 largest files in a directory\n");
printf("2. List all zero length files in a directory\n");
printf("3. Find all files with permission 777 in a directory\n");
printf("4. Create a backup of a directory\n");
printf("\n");
printf("ENTER YOUR CHOICE: ");
scanf("%d", &choice);
printf("Enter a directory name in the current directory: ");
scanf("%s", &input_dir_name);
/**********************************************************/

printf(input_dir_name);//Segmentation Fault (core dumped) 

/*Form a full path to the directory and check if it exists*/
/**********************************************************/


if(choice == 1){
    printf("\nEXECUTING \"1. Find the 3 largest files in a directory\"\n");
    /********************************************************/
    /**************Function to perform choice 1**************/
    /********************************************************/

}

else if(choice == 2){
    printf("\nEXECUTING \"2. List all zero length files in a directory\"\n");
    /********************************************************/
    /**************Function to perform choice 2**************/
    /********************************************************/

}

else if(choice == 3){
    printf("\nEXECUTING \"3. Find all files with permission 777 in a      directory\"\n");
    /********************************************************/
    /**************Function to perform choice 3**************/
    /********************************************************/

}

else if(choice == 4){
    printf("\nEXECUTING \"4. Create a backup of a directory\"\n");
    /********************************************************/
    /**************Function to perform choice 4**************/
    /********************************************************/
}

else{
    printf("Invalid choice\n");
    exit(1);
}
free(input_dir_name);
free(dirpath);
return 0;
}
```

========================================================================================
Here is the find.h file with my findfile function:

```
#include <stdio.h>      // Standard input/output routines    
#include <stdlib.h>     // Standard library routines    
#include <dirent.h>     // readdir(), etc.                    
#include <sys/stat.h>       // stat(), etc.                       
#include <string.h>     // strstr(), etc.                     
#include <unistd.h>     // getcwd(), etc.
#define MAX_DIR_PATH 2048   // Maximal full path length we support

/*===========================================================================
 *   
 *   Function: findfile recusively traverses the current directory, searching
 *   for files with a given string in their name. Hence strstr().
 *   Input:    String to match.
 *   Output:   Any file found, printed to the screen with a full path.
 *   
 ============================================================================*/
void findfile (char *pattern)
{   

  DIR *dir;         // Pointer to the scanned directory
  struct dirent *entry;     //  Pointer to one directory entry
  char cwd[MAX_DIR_PATH + 1];   // Current working directory
  struct stat dir_stat;     // Used by stat()

// First, save the path of current working directory 

if (!getcwd (cwd, MAX_DIR_PATH + 1))
{
  perror ("getcwd:");
  return;
}


// Open the directory to read

 dir = opendir (".");
 if (!dir)
{
  fprintf (stderr, "Cannot read directory '%s': ", cwd);
  perror ("");
  return;
}


  /*=======================================================
   * 
   * Scan the directory, traversing each sub-directory, and 
   * matching the pattern for each file / directory name. 
   *
   ========================================================*/

while ((entry = readdir (dir)))
{
  // Check if the pattern matches

  if (entry->d_name && strstr (entry->d_name, pattern))
{
  printf ("%s/%s\n", cwd, entry->d_name);
}

  // Check if the given entry is a directory

  if (stat (entry->d_name, &dir_stat) == -1)
{
  perror ("stat:");
  continue;
}

  // Skip the "." and ".." entries, to avoid loops

  if (strcmp (entry->d_name, ".") == 0)
continue;

  if (strcmp (entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
continue;

  /* Is this a directory? */
  if (S_ISDIR (dir_stat.st_mode))
{
  /* Change into the new directory */
  if (chdir (entry->d_name) == -1)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Cannot chdir into '%s': ", entry->d_name);
      perror ("");
      continue;
    }

  /* check this directory */
  findfile (pattern);

  /* Finally, restore the original working directory. */

  if (chdir ("..") == -1)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Cannot chdir back to '%s': ", cwd);
      perror ("");
      exit (1);
    }
}
 }
 }
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see where this crashes. And when posting on a Q&A site like this, please try to reduce the amount of code to just a small sample.

Comment: Starting program: /home/kuse0011/4061/a.out

SELECT THE FUNCTION YOU WANT TO EXECUTE:
1. Find the 3 largest files in a directory
2. List all zero length files in a directory
3. Find all files with permission 777 in a directory
4. Create a backup of a directory

ENTER YOUR CHOICE: 1
Enter a directory name in the current directory: lab4

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strchrnul () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S:34
34      ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
===================================================================

Comment: The file does exist.  I can see it in my directory.

Comment: Ignore that line from gdb; that's not where you're crashing. Make sure you compile your program with debug symbols, like `gcc -g you_program.c`. Then run through gdb and when it crashes, check the backtrace  through `bt`. This will tell you where you're crashing. Then you can figure out where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

scanf("%s", &input_dir_name);

to:

scanf("%s", input_dir_name);

BTW, header files (*.h) are not normally used for implementation of functions.  They are typically for declaration only of functions, macros, and variables.  Implementation (definition) is done in *.c/*.cpp files.